# nodejs expressjs sendFile with angular resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have my index.html, when I click on a button, it calls a angular service that use $resource.

```
var serviceRest = $resource(URL_API, null,
    {
       "connect" : { method: "GET", url: "http://localhost/login"}
     });
```

And then in my expressJS route I have this :

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log("Hi there");
    res.sendFile('../public/views/login.html', {root: __dirname});
});
```

But it does nothing. Nothing happens but my console log display so my sendFile might be false... I stay on my index.html.

```
| -- Agenda
     | -- public
          | -- views
               | -- login.html
     | -- controllers
          | -- routes.js
```

My router file is in `./controllers`, and my login.html is in `./public/views`

**EDIT :**

Ok, so the problem is not a path problem. But, in all solution that I tried, only one gave me a good result.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/views/login.html'));
```

After that, I asked myself "What I am returning in the Angular Service with the $resource. And this is at this moment that I saw that my `connect()` function :

```
var serviceRest = $resource(URL_API, null,
{ 
    "connect" : { method: "GET", url: "http://localhost/login"}
});

return {

    connect: function() {
        console.log("connect");
        console.log(serviceRest.connect());
        return serviceRest.connect();

    }
}
```

This `console.log(serviceRest.connect());` shows me a Promise in the browser console. And this is a huge array with one character per element, that containing my login.html code lol. Funny but not help me haha

Comment: did you configure router to process /login?

Comment: What do you mean by "process /login" ? Yeah that's note router.get('/'....
But it's really /login, my console.log("Hi there"); is display when I click on button. So it enter in the router.get

Comment: If it's your ask, I have this yes on my server.js : app.use('/login', login);

Comment: your login.html is in /public/views but you are sending ../public/login.html???

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. But it doesn't work after this edit...

Comment: do you have this line app.use(express.static('public')); in your code?

Comment: Yeah, to be right I have this two lines : 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
and
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/public/views"));

Comment: remove .. from ../public/views/login.html and try. i'm not sure is this your problem or other

Comment: No, I try that you recommend me and some others ways and nothing work. That sounds weird this problem. And I believe that sendFile only work with absolute path and not considering the express static (to be confirmed).

Answer (score 1):

**root** option is the directory from which you want to serve the files from. Assuming your folder structure is like below :

```
| yourApp
  | -- public/
       | -- views/
         |-- login.html
  | -- controllers/
       | -- routes.js
```

Try setting the root directory with **yourApp**

```
res.sendFile('public/views/login.html', {root: '../<root folder name>'});
```

Replace the "root folder name" above with the parent directory name of '**public**' folder.
Considering the above folder structure that would be :

```
res.sendFile('public/views/login.html', {root: '../yourApp'});
```

Comment: In my case the "yourApp" folder is name "Agenda". 
So I try that you said to me : res.sendFile('public/views/login.html', {root: '../Agenda'}); And it's not working... I also tried with a really aboslute path juste like this res.sendFile('C:\\Users\\.....'); and the same result.. This res.sendFile makes me mad

Comment: I edited my question, I have more details about the problems